# Unable to use Azure Publish Settings Files for VM management

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I'm trying to use an azure PUBLISHSETTINGS file as a way to run powershell scripts requiring authentication without having to log in every few days. From the research I've done I assumed that if you had a publishsettings file imported into your powershell, you could run any cmdlets against any of the subscriptions that the publishsettings file contains. When I import my files and run basic cmdlets (Get-AzureVM) I get:

```
Get-AzureVM : Your Azure credentials have not been set up or have expired,
please run Add-AzureAccount to set up your Azure credentials.
```

I have no issue adding my own Azure Account to that specific powershell instance but from what I understood once I've imported the files I shouldn't have to.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: Please provide the whole code not the piece of code, how you are using your publishsetting file  to connect to azure

Comment: The code is 3 cmdlets, Select-AzureSubscription, Get-AzureVM, and Start-AzureVM. 

I'm importing it via the Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile. I didn't realize there were other ways to connect my publishsettings file to azure.